# pandas read_csv fix columns to read data with newline characters in data

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Using pandas to read in large tab delimited file

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep='\t', encoding='latin 1', dtype = str, keep_default_na=False, na_values='')
```

The problem is that there are 200 columns and the 3rd column is text with occasional newline characters.  The text is not delimited with any special characters.  These lines get chopped into multiple lines with data going into the wrong columns.

There are a fixed number of tabs in each line - that is all I have to go on.

Comment: I do not think you can do it in Pandas alone. But you can preprocess the file(s) and replace all line breaks with some other acceptable character, unless they happen after N tabs in each row.

Comment: when the line gets chopped off, does the values in remaining  columns get NaN??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The idea is to use regex to find all instances of stuff separated by a given number of tabs and ending in a newline.  Then take all that and create a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

def wonky_parser(fn):
    txt = open(fn).read()
    #                          This is where I specified 8 tabs
    #                                        V
    preparse = re.findall('(([^\t]*\t[^\t]*){8}(\n|\Z))', txt)
    parsed = [t[0].split('\t') for t in preparse]
    return pd.DataFrame(parsed)
```

Pass a filename to the function and get your dataframe back.

Answer (score 2):

name your third column

```
df.columns.values[2] = "some_name"
```

and use converters to pass your function.

```
pd.read_csv("foo.csv", sep='\t', encoding='latin 1', dtype = str, keep_default_na=False, converters={'some_name':lambda x:x.replace('/n','')})
```

you could use any manipulating function which works for you under lambda.

Comment: tried this on my similar problem but didn't work for me unfortunately 
Also I think you would want to specify column names while reading using `names` or `header` and then pass the column name to the `converter`

Comment: Didn't work, I guess the converters are only applied AFTER data is separated into rows and columns (which fails due to newline chars in text)