# How can I remove control characters with python pandas on csv import?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, data-cleaning

I'm trying to import a csv file into pandas for manipulation.  I believe the file is encoded as utf-8-sig.  For some reason on input, pandas is executing the ^M characters in one of the strings which breaks it into multiple lines on output.  Is there any way to tell pandas to ignore any control characters in the row when importing?

Here is an example of a row that is causing the problems (with the ^M character):

```
1833367012,Some text here^M^M(some more text)^M^Mand some more text,198578879962592121,A NAME,someone@something.com,United States,2021-07-01,2021-07-01T11:57:58,2021-07-01T14:33:55,156,WINDOWS,IE,10.15.72.8,55.23.12.15,1.296,NA,NA,NA,NA,N,N,N,NA,Meeting Client,7.6.2.10,"Chicago, USA",ethernet,Computer,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,6.93,20
```

becomes

```
1863967051,Some text here,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
(some more text),,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
and some more text,198578879962592121,A NAME,someone@something.com,United States,2021-07-01,2021-07-01T11:57:58,2021-07-01T14:33:55,156,WINDOWS,IE,10.15.72.8,55.23.12.15,1.296,NA,NA,NA,NA,N,N,N,NA,Meeting Client,65.6.2.10,"Chicago, USA",ethernet,Computer,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,7,20,
```

The import I'm using is:

```
df = pd.read_csv(path_filename, quotechar='"', thousands=',', skipinitialspace=True, encoding='utf_8_sig')
```

Comment: Can you post a link to a sample csv that has the problem?

Comment: The sample line is above.  After a lot of research, it looks like it is not possible to ignore line breaks on import in pandas.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45453093/pandas-read-csv-fix-columns-to-read-data-with-newline-characters-in-data

I also used the csv module in python and it too cannot be made to ignore line breaks (the ^M).

Looks like the only option I've got is to build the dataframe with my own csv text parser.

Comment: In your sample line `^M` is not a newline control character (just two normal characters), seeing a few lines from the real file would have helped. Normally fields with actual newlines in are quoted and Pandas would correctly parse them. It might have been possible to pre-parse the file. Good luck